# Dynamic Programming: Why Knuth's improvement to Optimal Binary Search Tree O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming

This is Exercise 15.5-4 of Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition, which is about Knuth's improvement to the DP approach to Optimal Binary Search Tree.

The DP algorithm of Optimal Binary Search Tree is:

```
OPTIMAL_BST(p, q, n)
let e[1..n+1, 0..n], w[1..n+1, 0..n], and root[1..n, 1..n] be new tables
for i = 1 to n+1
    e[i, i - 1] = q[i - 1];
    w[i, i - 1] = q[i - 1];
for l = 1 to n
    for i = 1 to n - l + 1
        j = i + l - 1
        e[i, j] = INFINITY
        w[i, j] = w[i, j - 1] + p[j] + q[j]
        for r = i to j
            t = e[i, r - 1] + e[r + 1, j] + w[i, j]
            if t < e[i, j]
            e[i, j] = t
            root[i, j] = r
return e and root
```

The complexity is O(n<sup>3</sup>).
Knuth had observed that `root[i, j - 1] <= root[i, j] <= root[i + 1, j]`, so Exercise 15.5-4 asks to implement an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm by doing some modification to the original algorithm.

Well after some effort I have figured this out: in the innermost loop, replace the line

```
for r = i to j
```

with

```
for r = r[i, j - 1] to r[i + 1, j]
```

This has been proved by this link: [Optimal binary search trees](http://web.archive.org/web/20110117005522/http://www.ics.uci.edu:80/%7Edan/class/161/notes/6/OptBST.html)

However, I'm not sure this is really O(n<sup>2</sup>): since during each innermost loop, distance from r[i, j - 1] to r[i + 1, j] is not constant, I suspect it is still O(n<sup>3</sup>).

So my question is: can you please explain to me why the improvement to DP algorithm yields O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity?

PS: Maybe I might have read Knuth's paper first, but really I searched the web but found no free access to the paper.

Comment: What do you mean by r[i, j - 1] or r[i + 1, j] ? What is r indexing? Guibao and @Saeed

Comment: @Teaman: I think he means root[i, j-1] and root[i+1, j].

The loop with l is choosing the length of the slice into e. The variables i and j denote the left and right boundaries of the slice. The loop with the variable m sets the position of the root within the slice.

Comment: @Teaman: The Knuth Optimization gives us a stricter bound on m. Instead of iterating over m = i...j, we can iterate over m=root[i][j-1]...root[i+1][j].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're correct that the distance from `r[i, j - 1]` to `r[i + 1, j]` is not constant in the worst case, but it is constant on average, which suffices to imply a quadratic running time. The total number of iterations for `l` is

```
  S = sum_{i = 1}^{n - l + 1} (r[i + 1, j] + 1 - r[i, j - 1]),  j = i + l - 1
    = sum_{i = 1}^{n - l + 1} (r[i + 1, i + l - 1] + 1 - r[i, i + l - 2])
    = r[n - l + 2, n] + n - l + 1 - r[1, l - 1]
```

[image: latex]

therefore the average is S / (n - l + 1), which is a constant

by simplifying the telescoping sum.

Comment: Hi @SaeedAmiri both your answer and David's one directs to the same end. For the sake of usefulness for others, I'm marking David's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the exact running time analysis with a google search or just start to write your own analysis w.r.t for loops. But just note that in all of them sum in total is calculated by telescopic sum, I mean may be one of them is big but in each iteration for first loop takes O(n), and totally takes O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: @KevinGoedecke, the link is not the main part of the answer, but the explanation is important, as otherwise I was able to write a detailed proof, which is extra.

Comment: @KevinGoedecke, I removed the link.